# HttpClient POST with HttpParams

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am attempting to POST to an endpoint that requires arguments are passed as query string parameters and not via the POST body.

```
const params = new HttpParams()
  .set('param1', '1')
  .set('param2', '2');

const url = environment.apiUrl + 'Service/Endpoint';

return this
  .httpClient
  .post<ServiceResponse>(url, { params })
  .pipe(map(res => res.httpStatusCodeSuccess));
```

This is returning a 404 as the call does not include any querystring parameters.  I have verified this by looking at the network call.

This same code *does* work for me against GET requests if I am using `.get()` but isn't working with `.post()` against a POST endpoint.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you positive the endpoint is configured as you expect? Are you able to get the expected behavior when you test it with a `curl` command or with Postman?

Comment: @Pytth It works in Postman if I call it as `Service/Endpoint?param1=1&param2=2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of [`post`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) is the http body that you want to send in the request. If there is no body then pass `null` for the argument. Then pass the params as the 3rd argument of the call.

```
  .post<ServiceResponse>(url, null, { params: params })
```

The reason that `get` has a different method signature is that you can't pass a http body with a http get call.

Comment: Thank you for this! I've been missing this explanation for weeks

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are passing the params as an object.

Refer to below example

```
const myheader = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

let body = new HttpParams();

body = body.set('username', USERNAME);
body = body.set('password', PASSWORD);

http.post('/api', body, {
    headers: myheader),
})
```